# MySql Try to create a table from columns from two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to created a table from a few columns from two other tables. I want this table to get data from the other two tables.
This is what I have so far

```
insert into crm_customer_coupon (barcode, customer_id,customer_name, coupon_name, number_of_times_used, product_sku)
select barcode, name, sku
From crm_coupons
Inner left Join crm_customer_extra_information where customer_id = 88
```

This is one of the tables rm_coupons set up

```
id: Barcode: Name : Description: Type : Amount : sku
```

This is the table rm_customer_extra_information

```
id : name: customer_id : ect...
```

and this is the table I want to put them into

```
 barcode: customer_id : customer_name: coupon_name: product_sku
```

How do I go about combining them together, also how are they linked so I can get information from the other tables via a endpoint in spring later on.
Thank you for any help with this

Comment: You should know this one: _How do I go about combining them together_.
At least tell us how those 2 tables are linked together.

Comment: The third table is what values I want out of the two other tables. I just don't know how to get the values out that I want. It is a assignment table where I want to link coupons to customers in the third table

Comment: Still the question remains: How are we going to know which coupons belong to a specific customer?

Comment: It will be a M2M connection. I want to be able to assign different coupons to some based off of criteria, but I think that using the customer id to link to the coupon would be best

Comment: Yes, I understand that the table you are trying to create is a junction table. But if you already have records on customers and coupons tables, how are we going to know which coupons belong to a specific customer? Show us how those two tables are related. Does the customer has a couponId somewhere (or from other tables), or vice versa?

Comment: I think I see what you getting at, I am making the connection between them myself in the third table. So from the third table I can get the information from the other tables as I need

Comment: Look, if you don't know which coupons belong to a specific customer, and which customers belong to a specific coupon, you cannot insert records (for existing customers and coupons) to the new table that you are trying to create. You can insert records for new customers and coupons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into crm_customer_coupon (barcode,name,sku)
select crm_coupons.barcode, crm_customer_extra_information.coupon_name, crm_coupons.sku
from crm_coupons
left Join crm_customer_extra_information on crm_coupons.id=crm_customer_extra_information.id
where customer_id = 88
```

You forgot to mention you join field (i guess it's id),
also you didn't mention which name field you want to insert, i put coupon_name, you can change the filed name in the subquery select.

Comment: did you created crm_customer_coupon?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where customer_id = 88 on crm_coupons.id=crm_customer_extra_information.id' at line 4

Comment: there is a table but no data

Comment: try now i've changed the script, where condition should be after the join

Answer (score 0):

It's easy:

```
   CREATE TABLE new_table 
      SELECT barcode, name,sku 
      FROM crm_coupons 
      // your code here
```